# Excel VBA function to update cells value += cell aboves value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]

How can I make it so that if I enter anything into cell range B3:E3 the value will be whatever I input, plus the value of the above cell.

example: If I input 20 into cell C3, once I hit return or click away the value will be updated to 40.

So far I know I need to have something similar to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("B3:E3").Value = Range("B2:E2").Value

End Sub
```

And I know I need to somehow access the offset value, but VBA is not my forte and I cant seem to word this question correctly.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15337093/2071807) of any help?

Comment: no because its updates the cell everytime you click anywhere on the sheet

Comment: You can make the event range-specific by doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15337093/2071807)

Comment: Rather than changing your question, it might be better for future readers of this question if you left it as it was and asked a new question instead. You can link to this question for reference. (p.s. let's hope the people of [Whitby](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=yo213pu) don't mind you sharing their soft drink preferences!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a load of error-checking to this, but here's the bare bones:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ' If we're not in the range of interest
  ' do nothing.
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:E2")) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
  ' We don't want this event to fire itself!
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  ' Now add the row above (rowOffset = -1) to the value.
  Target.Value = Target.Value + Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value
  ' Don't forget to re-enable events, otherwise there'll
  ' be no more VBA events fired.
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works but if I click around the sheet, the cell in question continues to increment, I want to only increment if the cell in question has been changed

Comment: Note that my function is `Worksheet_Change` not `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

Comment: this works, can it be applied to the below rows too?

Comment: Just change the value of the row offset from `-1` to `1`

Comment: the first line though, IS NOTHING THEN Exit Sub, means any additional logic below is not run. And I cant duplicate the sub and changed the code as I cant have the same ambigious function

Comment: ill ask a new question